# why do I get different summary results for lmList vs lmList[[x]]

Tags: r, regression

I was using `lmList` from `nlme` package to run various regressions based on different groups the by function. I'm a bit confused regarding the summary results given the explanation I see for `summary.lmList`

```
The `summary.lm` method is applied to each lm component of object to produce
summary information on the individual fits, which is organized into a list of
summary statistics. 

The returned object is suitable for printing with the print.summary.lmList
method.
```

What I mean is the below

```
set.seed(123)
t <- data.frame(
        name=sample(c("a","b","c"),size=500,replace=T),
        x=1:500,
        y=1:500+rnorm(100)
      )
ta <- t[t$name=="a",]
lma <- lm(y~x,ta)
lmL <- lmList(y~x | name,t)
r1 <- summary(lmL)  
r2 <- summary(lmL[["a"]])  
r3 <- summary(lma)
```

Can someone please explain to me why the values displayed for "a" in r1 do not match those in r2 and r3, while those in r2 match those in r3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The versions of `lmList` and it's summary method in **nlme** have an argument `pool`:

> an optional logical value indicating whether a pooled estimate of the
>   residual standard error should be used in calculations of standard
>   deviations or standard errors for summaries.

I'm guessing that if you set that to `FALSE` when you call `summary` you'll get identical values.